# Cannot create keyspace with cassandra with php

Tags: php, docker, cassandra, cqlsh, phpcassa

I can't create keyspace on cassandra running under docker containor with PHP. The connexion seems to be ok but i have nothing created. when i run `DESCRIBE keyspaces;` i have only keyspaces created by default.

I'm using `thobbs/phpcassa` bundle to connect php with cassandra.
I think that the problem seems to be with login and password.

In  this bundle, i didn't found where i put them. When i connect to cassandra container, i can connect by this command `cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra 172.24.0.1 9042`

Bellow is my code on index.php

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use phpcassa\ColumnFamily;
use phpcassa\ColumnSlice;
use phpcassa\Connection\ConnectionPool;

$servers = array("172.24.0.1:9042");
$pool = new ConnectionPool("Keyspace2", $servers);


$column_family = new ColumnFamily($pool, 'ColumnFamily1');
```

where i can put my login and password ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use `thobbs/phpcassa` - it's very old, and it uses legacy Thrift protocol under the hood... The correct way is to work with Cassandra now is to use [PHP driver from DataStax](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver).  Authentication is fully supported there ([doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/php-driver/1.3/features/#authenticating-via-password-authenticator)), like this:

```php
$cluster = Cassandra::cluster()
               ->withCredentials("username", "password")
               ->build();
$session = $cluster->connect();
```

And after you got `$session`, you can use `execute` function to execute CQL statements, like, [CREATE KEYSPACE](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateKeyspace.html) and [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateTable.html), like this:

```
$session->execute('CREATE TABLE ...')
```

I recommend to learn about CQL (Cassandra Query Language) that replaced the Thrift long time ago.  The good resource for it is "Cassandra. The definitive guide book" - the 3rd edition of it was recently released, and [freely available from the DataStax site](https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide).

Comment: That's perfect. It worked for me. Now, i can query from cassandra database.